# Java: GatheringByteChannel advantages?

Tags: java, nio

I'm wondering when the [GatheringByteChannel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/GatheringByteChannel.html)'s write methods (taking in an array of ByteBuffers) have advantages over the "regular" WritableByteChannel write methods.

I tried a test where I could use the regular vs. the gathering write method on a FileChannel, with approx 400KB/sec total in ByteBuffers of between 23-27 bytes in length in both cases. Gathering writes used an array of 64. The regular method used up approx 12% of my CPU, and the gathering method used up approx 16% of my CPU (worse than the regular method!)

This tells me it's NOT useful to use gathering writes on a FileChannel around this range of operating parameters. Why would this be the case, and when would you ever use GatheringByteChannel? (on network I/O?)

Relevant differences here:

```
public void log(Queue<Packet> packets) throws IOException
{
    if (this.gather)
    {
        int Nbuf = 64;
        ByteBuffer[] bbufs = new ByteBuffer[Nbuf];
        int i = 0;
        Packet p;
        while ((p = packets.poll()) != null)
        {
            bbufs[i++] = p.getBuffer();
            if (i == Nbuf)
            {
                this.fc.write(bbufs);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            this.fc.write(bbufs, 0, i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Packet p;
        while ((p = packets.poll()) != null)
        {
            this.fc.write(p.getBuffer());
        }
    }
}
```

**update:**

I did some testing and the gathering approach for various lengths of ByteBuffers seems to have no benefit for file I/O. Far more relevant was the "fragmentation" of the I/O stream via byte buffer length. I changed my program so it copied a relatively large (27MB) file via reading the input into byte buffers of a particular length. The program starts to slow down significantly if the buffers are less than 256 bytes in length.

I decided to try a third option, namely to write my own simple "gathering" routine that takes buffers and consolidates them into a larger buffer before writing to a filechannel. This blows away the GatheringByteChannel `write(ByteBuffer[] buffers)` method for speed. (Note: The *reading* size is the same for all three modes of writing, so the fact that I'm creating a bunch of small ByteBuffers and using them to read I/O isn't causing a significant slowdown.) I'm kind of disappointed that Java doesn't just do this for you. Oh well.

```
enum GatherType { NONE, AUTOMATIC, MANUAL }

static class BufferWriter
{
    final private FileChannel fc;
    private GatherType gather = GatherType.NONE;

    BufferWriter(FileChannel f) { this.fc = f; } 

    public void setGather(GatherType gather) { this.gather=gather; }
    public void write(Queue<ByteBuffer> buffers) throws IOException
    {
        switch (this.gather)
        {
            case AUTOMATIC:
            {
                int Nbuf = 64;
                ByteBuffer[] bbufs = new ByteBuffer[Nbuf];
                int i = 0;
                ByteBuffer b;
                while ((b = buffers.poll()) != null)
                {
                    bbufs[i++] = b;
                    if (i == Nbuf)
                    {
                        this.fc.write(bbufs);
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    this.fc.write(bbufs, 0, i);
                }
            }
            break;
            case MANUAL:
            {
                ByteBuffer consolidatedBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
                ByteBuffer b;
                while ((b = buffers.poll()) != null)
                {
                    if (b.remaining() > consolidatedBuffer.remaining())
                    {
                        consolidatedBuffer.flip();
                        this.fc.write(consolidatedBuffer);
                        consolidatedBuffer.clear();
                    }

                    if (b.remaining() > consolidatedBuffer.remaining())
                    {
                        this.fc.write(b);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        consolidatedBuffer.put(b);
                    }
                }

                consolidatedBuffer.flip();
                if (consolidatedBuffer.hasRemaining())
                {
                    this.fc.write(consolidatedBuffer);
                }
            }
            break;
            case NONE:
            {
                ByteBuffer b;
                while ((b = buffers.poll()) != null)
                {
                    this.fc.write(b);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use more than 16 buffers for a read or a write.  I know Java 5 had a hard limit of 16 (would accept more but would only read/write 16 of them) due to limit within Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

GatheringByteChannel and ScatteringByteChannel maps to writev and readv system calls (or equivalent on other systems) with struct iovec to hold multiple buffers.

For a network socket this means that the data will appear in the same network frame to the extent that it would if all data were in one buffer. This might be used to encode a header in a one buffer, load data from a file into another direct buffer but be written to the socket as if they were one continuous buffer. If writev semantics were not used in this case, the header and file data might be written in separate network frames which has significant implications at the network level.

For a file, writing multiple buffers as if they were one has implications for file consistency. If you write data to a file with two separate writes and the second write fails, the file data will not be consistent. Write operations are atomic as far as the operating system is concerned (although that wasn't always true and may not be true for certain systems). When writev is used, the file should be consistent and get both buffers or neither.

Answer (score -3):

Does `packets.poll()` creates every time a new `Buffer`? If not, your are writing wrong data in the first case.